# Bootstrap Carousel Control - change them to arrow with circle background

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-4

I'd like to change the styles of the Bootstrap 4 carousel icons from the arrows to arrows with a dark semi-opaque circles underneath.

I realise the icons themselves are svg's but I'm not sure how to make svg's or amend them to do what I want.

This is the Bootstrap code that generates the svg.

```
    .carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the icon directly from SVG file. Inspect the part and change the color in the 'fill' attribute with the color you like.

You can also change color by adding hex color in " fill='%23fff' " from above css.
eg: fill='%23A0A0A0' where 'A0A0A0' is the shade of grey. Here, 'fff' is white, and '000' will be black.

Or simply use invert/grayscale css filter in the icon. eg:

```
.carousel-control-next{
    filter: invert(60%);
}
```